# Refactoring huge if ( ... instanceof ...)

Tags: java, oop

I'm currently trying to refactor a part of a project that looks like this:

Many classes

```
 B extends A; C extends A; D extends C; E extends B; F extends A; ...
```

And somewhere in the code:

```
if (x instanceof B){
 B n = (B) x;
 ...
}else if (x instanceof C){
 C n = (C) x;
 ...
}else if (x instanceof D){
 D n = (D) x;
 ...
}else if (x instanceof E){
 E n = (E) x;
 ...
}else if (x instanceof G){
 G n = (G) x;
 ...
}...
```

Above if-construct currently sits in a function with a CC of 19. Now my question is: Can I split this if-construct up in mutliple functions and let Java's OO do the magic? Or are there any catches I have to look out for?

My idea:

```
private void oopMagic(C obj){ ... Do the stuff from the if(x instanceof C) here}
private void oopMagic(D obj){ ... Do the stuff from the if(x instanceof D) here}
private void oopMagic(E obj){ ... Do the stuff from the if(x instanceof E) here}
....
```

and instead of the huge if:

```
oopMagic(x);
```

**Edit:** I cannot change any of the classes (A,B,C,...). Inside the if statements some getters are used to read (never write) data from each object.

Comment: What was the original author thinking?

Comment: @darioo Perhaps "I wish this was Scala with support for algebraic data types and pattern matching" :p

Comment: @darioo, @pst: or perhaps something like "I'll do this quick and dirty *just this once*" and in time subclasses kept coming... and coming...

Comment: i believe you are just moving around the problem instead of refactoring it ;-)

Comment: @Goran: "I'll do this quick and dirty just this once" -> hello, technical debt!

Comment: @darioo: Yeah, now it has a fancy name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That won't fly. `instanceof` detects the **runtime** type of a variable.  Polymorphism (select method by signature) depends on the **compile-time** type of a variable.  That is, you'll always get `oopMagic(A obj)`.

As Roger suggested, take a look at the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), a.k.a double-dispatch.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell what would work best since you haven't given any indication what the code is doing, but another option is to add an `oopMagic()` method to `A` and override as necessary.

Comment: Best solution if every subclass of A has to do some magic and if your able to provide a default implementation. Otherwise you could extract your magic into a strategy and introduce a new interface for all classes which should be magical ;) Would be really interesting what ... exactly does.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change the the classes, you may still be able to wrap them and introduce a factory to create a correct wrapper for your type:

---

```
public interface Wrapper {
  public void magicMethod();  // you know what I mean
}
```

---

```
public AWrapper implements Wrapper {
  private A a;
  public AWrapper(A a){this.a=a;};

  @Override
  public void magicMethod() {
    // do what has to be done with a
  }
}
```

---

```
public Factory {
  public static createWrapper(Object wrappable) {
    if (wrappable instanceof A)
        return new AWrapper((A) wrappable);
    // ...
  }
}
```

---

```
// ...
Object x = getXFromSomewhere();
Wrapper wrapper = Factory.getWrapper(x);
wrapper.magicMethod();
// ...
```

Sure, this will not eliminate the sequence of `instanceof` statements but it will move it to a factory and that's at least a better place. Factory methods almost always contain some conditional checks which are needed to create the correct object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid (as also suggested by one commenter) you just move the problem somewhere else, e.g. the if-else will be done in other place. There is no problem with your approach but to make it better you have to do some more work.

What I suggest is to create a Map that will process x according to its type. Processor itself is a generic interface, something like:

```
interface Processor<T extends A> {
     void oopMagic(T obj);
}
```

Then create implementation of the processor for each class, something like:

```
class ProcessorB<B> {
     void oopMagic(B obj) { ... }
}
```

Put all implementation class in the map and then do:

```
map.get(x.getClass()).oopMagic(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what's in those `...`s, you could get away with making a virtual (maybe abstract) method `doMagic` in the base class and then just:

```
x.doMagic();
```

If the `...` parts are sufficiently different, then (apart from having other problems with the design), you could look at implementing double-dispatch using the visitor pattern.